# Python — Iterating Through Two Lists Simultaneously

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a translator for a cipher I made up, and it needs to be able to check 2 lists side by side, but my program does not return any output.

```py
def encrypt(message, key):
  
    for i in range(len(message)):
        ans = ""
        char = message[i]
        
        if(char == 1):
            for j in range(len(key)):  
                if(key[j] == 1):
                    ans = 'a'
                if(key[j] == 0):
                    ans = 'c'


        if(char == 0):
            for j in range(len(key)):
                if(key[j] == 1):
                    ans = 'd'
                if(key[j] == 0):
                    ans = 'b'   
    return ans
print(encrypt(str(1010), str(1100)))
```

I want this to output "adcb". I think there's a problem with where I put the return statement? I don't know.

Comment: There are several errors in your code - `'1' != 1`, you'll always get the same results once you fix that, because you always loop over the entire key with `j` and always find a `0` at the end; you should look at `zip()`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Aside for @Grismar's comments,  you aren't concatenating your ```ans```, thusly you'll only return one letter after all that is done.

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to loop over two strings of equal length, containing only the characters `'0'` and `'1'` and you want to return a string of equal length containing an `'a'` if both characters at that position are `'1'` for the inputs, etc.

So, something like:

```
def encrypt(message, key):
    code = {('1', '1'): 'a', ('1', '0'): 'c', ('0', '1'): 'd', ('0', '0'): 'b'}
    return ''.join(
        code[(m, k)] for m, k in zip(message, key)
    )


print(encrypt('1010', '1100'))
```

Result:

```
adcb
```

And to provide a 'fixed' version of what you were trying with a loop and indexing (which isn't very pythonic):

```
def encrypt(message, key):
    ans = ''

    for i in range(len(message)):
        m = message[i]
        k = key[i]
        if m == '1':
            if k == '1':
                ans += 'a'
            if k == '0':
                ans += 'c'
        if m == '0':
            if k == '1':
                ans += 'd'
            if k == '0':
                ans += 'b'

    return ans
```

Note that I've already removed the superfluous parentheses and the extra loops that give a wrong result.

You could further simplify:

```
def encrypt(message, key):
    ans = ''

    for i in range(len(message)):
        if message[i] == '1':
            if key[i] == '1':
                ans += 'a'
            else:
                ans += 'c'
        else:
            if key[i] == '1':
                ans += 'd'
            else:
                ans += 'b'

    return ans
```

And from there:

```
def encrypt(message, key):
    ans = ''

    for m, k in zip(message, key):        
        if m == '1':
            if k == '1':
                ans += 'a'
            else:
                ans += 'c'
        else:
            if k == '1':
                ans += 'd'
            else:
                ans += 'b'

    return ans
```

As an added bonus, here's a gnarly one-liner that goes just a bit too far, beyond being pythonic:

```
def encrypt(message, key):
    return ''.join('bdca'[int(m)*2 + int(k)] for m, k in zip(message, key))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the conditional statements `char == 1` and `char == 0`.  Since a string and a integer are two different data types, the conditional statements evaluate to `False` and the inner for loops never run, so the function returns no output.  To resolve this, change them to `char == '1'` and `char == '0'`.  Same rule applies for key[j] == 1 and key[j] == 0, because key is passed into the function as a string.